# Navigate back from FlutterDocumentPicker

Tags: flutter

I try to navigate back from `FlutterDocumentPicker, when a file was not selected, but it shows black screen and there is no error in console. How to fix it?

```
Future<void> _getFile(BuildContext context) async {
    final FlutterDocumentPickerParams params = FlutterDocumentPickerParams(
      allowedFileExtensions: ['txt'],
    );

    final String path = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument(params: params)
        .catchError((dynamic e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return; // ?
    });

    print(path); // null, i.e. file was not selected

    if (path == null) {
      // back button pressed i.e. file was not selected
      Navigator.pop(
          context); // can not find previous screen, it shows black screen, there is no error in console
      return; // ?
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I think you don't have to call `Navigator.pop()` whether the file is selected or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black screen means, your `root`/`main` widget has been popped out of the Navigation Stack. Meaning the widget you are trying to `pop` is not the `FlutterDocumentPicker` but the `root` widget.

I don't think you need to pop the current widget since the output `path` is available only after the `FlutterDocumentPicker` widget is disposed/closed.

Just `return` from the method, no need to pop the widget.